# How to create a event of CEP Ge using it,s rest API and interact it with my orion

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing, fiware-cep

I have launch a CEP instance on fiware-lab using cep-r5.4.3-img image.Now i want to perform a simple use case on CEP i.e. create a Event using it,s rest api.So i executed below command on postman:

POST:   http://XXx.XXX.xxx.xx:8080/ProtonUnitTest/rest/events

Header: Content-Type =application/json

{"Name": "event type name", "attr1": "value1", "attr2": "value2"}

then i get an error  404 not found.I also attach a screenshot of my error in postman at this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wtE5.jpg. Now what's the problem.But i able to create event from GUI.

In last if anyone can share me some an use case where CEP and Orion is interacting with steps by step.Thanks in advance.I also read many doc....

Answer (score 0):

We no longer recommend the usage of Proton.

Check Perseo

https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-fe
https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-core